# When "through" is interchangeable with "by"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I have this sentence

> Then, he specifies several anchors **by** selecting elements of the page.

Can I write it as follows ?

> Then, he specifies several anchors **through** selecting elements of the page.

I know sometimes we can use "through" means "by", but I don't know when!

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25459/what-general-rules-govern-the-usage-of-by-versus-through. The sentence that will likely be of interest to you is "As a very general rule of thumb, if literal or figurative motion or progression is involved, use through. Otherwise, use by."

Comment: 'through' looks bad as compared to 'by' in that sentence!

Comment: "Through" looks like AmE.